# can we update an atom state whenver another atom changes in RecoilJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

im quite new to recoiljs atom and stuff. Assumming i have 2 atoms

`timeRangeAtom` which determines the time range of the selection

```
export const timeRangeAtom = atom<Array<string>>({
   key: 'timeRangeAtom',
   default: [
       dayjs().subtract(7, 'day').format(DateFormat),
       dayjs().subtract(1, 'day').format(DateFormat),
       ],
});
```

`filterAtoms` which determines the current user selection of all filters ( one of them is `timeRange`)

```
export const filterAtom = atom<any>({
   key: 'filterAtom',
   default: {time: [] },
});
```

Now in my code, whenever user select a date, i will update the `timeRangeAtom` value. I'm doing this by calling `setTime` of `useRecoilState`

```
  const [time, setTime] = useRecoilState(
    timeRangeAtom,
  );
```

Now my question is how can i also sync this change to my `filterAtom.time` whenever `timeRangeAtom` change ?

One way is i manually setFilterAtom by calling useRecoilState, but it seems quite tedious and duplicate code. So im not sure is there any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create derived state from other atoms using the [selector](https://recoiljs.org/docs/basic-tutorial/selectors) API:

```js
export const filterAtom = selector({
  key: 'filterAtom',
  get: ({get}) => {
    const timeRange = get(timeRangeAtom);
    return {time: [...timeRange]};
  },
});
```

Comment: but in my filterAtom i also need to update it frequently, because there are also other value inside. If we use selector is this good, i thought selector mainly for get value only (even though they have set) thanks

Comment: @JakeLam I can't respond to code you haven't shown. My answer is a response to the information in your question.